# Unable to Playback videos using cv2_imshow in Google Colab

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

I am running the below command in Google Colab, in an attempt to return the cv2 predictions from a model I ran. When I use cv2_imshow(frame), it does not output the video. Is there any other code that I a missing, converting from cv2 to cvs_imshow?

Note I import a local mp4 file, called bib-detector-demo (1).mp4 onto my Google Drive first before I try running the below code execution cells.

```
def get_rbns(img, single=False):
    """
    Given an image return bib numbers and bib bounding boxes for detected bibs
    
    Args
        img (numpy array): image array given by openCV .imread
        single (bool): whether one or many bib detections will be
            returned.  If true, return detection with largest bounding
            box area.
            
    Returns
        List of detected bib numbers and corresponding bounding boxes in
        the format [<bib number>, [x, y, width, height]]
    """
    
    # Instantiate detectors
    bd = Detector(bd_configPath, bd_weightsPath, bd_classes)
    nr = Detector(nr_configPath, nr_weightsPath, nr_classes)

    # Make bib location predictions
    bib_detections = bd.detect(img, 0.25)


    if len(bib_detections) > 0:
        for obj in bib_detections:
            # crop out detected bib
            (x, y, w, h) = obj[1]
            obj.append(w * h)
            crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            
            # detect numbers on bib
            num_detections = nr.detect(crop_img, 0.5)
            bib_digit_loc = []
            if len(num_detections) > 0:
                # get digits and locations
                for digit in num_detections:
                    (d_x, d_y, d_w, d_h) = digit[1]
                    bib_digit_loc.append((d_x, str(digit[0])))

                # sort detected numbers L->R and put together
                bib_digit_loc.sort()
                rbn = int(''.join([i[1] for i in bib_digit_loc]))
                obj.append(rbn)
            else:
                obj.append(0) # bib detection but no digit detection

        if single: 
            if len(bib_detections) > 1:
                bib_detections.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
            return [[bib_detections[0][3], bib_detections[0][1]]]
        else:
            final_bibs = []
            for bib in bib_detections:
                final_bibs.append([bib[3], bib[1]])
            return final_bibs
    else: return None

from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow 
import cv2 as cv
%cp '/content/drive/MyDrive/bib-project/bib_detector_demo (1).mp4' '/usr/validation'

# path for video detection
video_path = '/usr/validation/bib_detector_demo (1).mp4'

# choose video or live webcam stream from below:
cap = cv.VideoCapture(video_path) # uncomment for video
# cap = cv.VideoCapture(0) # uncomment for live stream

# set ouput specifications
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v')
width = int(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
vid_out = cv.VideoWriter('/usr/validation/bib_detector_demo (1).mp4',fourcc, 25.0, (width,height))

from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    # get bib prediction
    output = get_rbns(frame, single=True)

    # annotate image
    if output != None:
        for detection in output:
            frame = annotate(frame, detection, color)

    #display annotated frame
    cv2_imshow(frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: limitation of colab/jupyter. these things have their own "GUI" facilities. you can't use OpenCV's `waitKey`. the `cv2_imshow` is a shim already, provided by google for colab.

Comment: Does this help with no whitespace  video_path = '/usr/validation/bib_detector_demo(1).mp4'?

Comment: And also this too  vid_out = cv.VideoWriter('/usr/validation/bib_detector_demo(1).mp4',fourcc, 25.0, (width,height))

Comment: Tried adjusting the file name to remove spaces & it still doesn’t output video

Comment: One last thing. How do u know which drive path? There is something missing video_path = '/usr/validation/bib_detector_demo (1).mp4'

Comment: Nothing is missing in the path: that’s how colab works in terms of directories

Comment: Does this help [link]https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/jupyter/display-opencv-video-in-jupyter/ ?